# Kubernetes cluster ... For science!

Tags: juju, conjure-up, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster. I want to find opportunities to contribute to scientific efforts with the compute and memory resources I have available.

I am interested in providing resources for

- math research
- cancer research
- SETI
- and more

Please advise with any recommended

- helm charts
- operators
- manifests

I am especially interested in ones that display performance information to see if the cluster is offering value to the efforts.

Thanks!